# Import text file into single field in Mysql

Tags: mysql, delphi

I have a datalogger collecting status from 4 machines. They all send a main status and some parameters which are stored in two text files, one to status and one to pms. I'll now try to read this parameter file to Mysql 8- database with old Delphi 7. With a 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' I can import the file but all parameters goes to different rows.

Instead of writing separate rows I would like to put all log data in one field like :

```
| ID  |     LOG      |  TIME  |
-------------------------------
|  1  | 12A21B22C32D | 104521 |
|     | 22176A22651B |        |
|     | 23123C44122D |        |
-------------------------------
|  2  | 11A21B22C33D | 104652 |
|     | 22156A22641B |        |
|     | 23123C44142D |        |
-------------------------------
```

There is maximum 18 rows in every log.
Can somebody help how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Your data structure breaks the rules of normalisation and is not really a great fit with an RDBMS. If you need unstructured data storage, then consider using a nosql solution.

Comment: You could use a Blob field to store the mentioned files in their raw format same as you would do with storing images and such.

Answer (score 1):

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` loads each row to a separate record.

If that's not what you want then you need to read the text file yourself, build an SQL INSERT statement, ideally with parameters for each column, setting those parameters to the values you want from the text file.  Then execute the UPDATE statement.

I never used Delphi 7, and you haven't mentioned what you are using to access the Database, so I can't provide more guidance than that.  With a modern version I would expect you to be using FireDac and a `TFDCommand` will do that for you easily.

Answer (score 0):

Create  a column of type xml

Insert into table
Select * From logtable For XML Raw

( create temporary logtable fir
st important the log data into it)